# Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] non-stop

Tags: ar.drone

I am working on AR.Drone 2.0 control application. I am using javadrone API and library in my project. Here is my code problem: whenever I press TakeOff button in my application, it will keep on sending takeoff commands to drone. And it ignore to issue the next AT command that I wanted to send. For example, I connect to drone, press TakeOff button (It should send AT TakeOffCommand,it works fine) but the next command (e.g.Flying Up) will not issue & send to drone. Why this happen? Any idea what cause this bug?

```
    My Java Code: 
        **Connect Button in my apps**
        private void jButtonConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

        try {
            // Create ARDrone object,
            // connect to drone and initialize it.
            drone = new ARDrone();
            drone.playLED(10,10,10);
            drone.connect();
            drone.clearEmergencySignal();

            // Wait until drone is ready
            drone.waitForReady(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            System.err.println("Drone State: " + drone.getState());
            // do TRIM operation
            drone.trim();  
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }              
    } 

    **Take Off Button in my apps**
     private void jButtonTakeOffActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
     try
     {     
        // Take off
        System.err.println("Taking off");
        drone.takeOff();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }catch (IOException ex) {  
            Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }  
    }  

    **Flying Up Button in java apps:**
    private void jButtonUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

     try
        {           
            // Flying Up
            drone.playAnimation(1,10);
            drone.move(0,0,5,0);
            // Fly a little :)
            Thread.sleep(5000);                  
         } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }                                         
}

**Output here:**
Current Drone State : CONNECTING 
Taking off 
6819 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG ardrone.ARDrone  - State changed from CONNECTING to TAKING_OFF 
6819 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[1]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] 
Take off command! 
7028 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[1]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] 
7129 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[1]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] 
7230 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[1]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] [These TakeOff AT commands will continuously send to drone] 
Flying Up! 
TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208]  
Movement Command Sending!
0.0
0.0
5.0
0.0 
9847 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[2]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] <--Why it still sending TakeOffCommand instead of MoveCommand ? 
Movement Command Sent Done! 
9947 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[3]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208] 
10047 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[3]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208]
```

I been working on this code for few weeks and still cannot identify the problem. Please help me to solve this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is OK, and even necessary.  From the [AR.Drone Developer Guide](http://www.msh-tools.com/ardrone/ARDrone_Developer_Guide.pdf):

> There are two cases when the local (client side) sequence counter
>   should be reset:
>
> - the drone does not receive any traffic for more that 50ms; it will    then set its ARDRONE_COM_WATCHDOG_MASK bit in the ardrone_state field 
>     (2nd field) of the navdata packet. To exit this mode, the client must 
>     send the AT Command AT*COMWDG.
> - The drone does not receive any traffic    for more than 2000ms; it will then stop all communication with the    client, and internally
>     set the ARDRONE_COM_LOST_MASK bit in its state    variable. The client
>     must then reinitialize the network communication    with the drone.

So the drone needs to receive something from your app every 50 milliseconds to continue operating normally.  The SDKs I've seen usually send `REF` and/or `PCMD` commands.  javadrone seems to be designed differently, and sends `COMWDG` (communications watchdog) messages to prevent timeouts).

[*Edited to include a small working test program*]

I don't know why your code isn't working, but here are a couple things you can try:

- I see you call `playLED` before you actually connect to the drone;
  you probably don't want to do that.
- I believe the arguments to `move` should be floats
  in the range [0.0, 1.0]--You're calling it with 5.

Here's a short program that takes off, and then begins moving backward.  I've tested it on my AR.Drone 2.0 with a fresh checkout and build of [javadrone](https://github.com/vzaliva/javadrone) and it works.  There are lots of exceptions, but it works: javadrone is pretty out of date at this point, and is primarily aimed at AR.Drone 1.0.  It seems to be unable to parse the drone's navdata, for one thing.

When I run this program, I see it send `REF` commands from the time I tell the drone to takeoff until the drone has finished taking off.  It then sends `COMWDG` commands until the code tells the drone to move, at which point it sends a `PCMD`, followed by `COMWDG` messages again.

I recommend trying this program with your drone to see if it works.  Make sure you're using a fresh checkout of javadrone.

```
import com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class DroneTest {

  private static final long CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10000L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ARDrone drone = new ARDrone();
      drone.connect();

      // Wait until drone is ready
      drone.waitForReady(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

      drone.clearEmergencySignal();
      System.err.println("Drone State: " + drone.getState());
      // do TRIM operation
      System.err.println("**********\nTRIM\n**********");
      drone.trim();
      Thread.sleep(5000);

      System.err.println("**********\nTAKEOFF\n**********");
      drone.takeOff();
      Thread.sleep(10000);

      System.err.println("**********\nMOVE\n**********");
      drone.move(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for pointing out this important message. Yes,I did notice that as well. However, this problem affect my next flight instruction for drone. 

As soon as I connected into the drone with the drone.takeOff() command,it just ignore other AT commands that I sent to. In fact, it seems like stuck in Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208]. 

For example, I issue flying up/down (pitch up/down) or rotate left/right. The apps just keep on sending TakeOffCommand instead of the right command.

Any idea what happen and how to solve this? 

Your reply really appreciated much!

Comment: What should happen when you tell the drone to move up/down/left/right/etc. is it should also begin sending PCMDs.  The REF commands are not a problem, but if it's not sending PCMD that is a problem.  Can you post the rest of your code that isn't working?

Comment: After connecting to drone, suppose I can issue any simple flight commands such as move up/down/left/right/etc. The drone should react to command accordingly. However it doesn't send out the appropriate REF and/or PCMD commands after I click TakeOff button as I mentioned above. It keeps on send takeoff commands to drone endlessly.

If I click "Up" button, it suppose send MoveCommand-PCMD command. But it doesn't issue MoveCommand while takeoff command just keeps on sending instead.

Comment: However, if I connect to drone and WITHOUT make the drone takeoff using drone.takeOff() command, the appropriate flight command will be send to drone. 

For example, if I hit Up button, it can issue the right AT command to drone and I think the drone should able to react to that particular AT command (flying up).

Problems occur when I use drone.takeoff(), the app won't bother to issue other AT commands. It just keeps on sending TakeOffCommand.

Comment: Sorry if I spam too much of info here but I try to make you to understand how this problem occur. So this is what I get when I debug the program. The output below (if I didn't hit TakeOff Button, it looks fine) :

Flying Right
20173 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender  - Q[0]Sending AT command MoveCommand [ID=PCMD, param=,3,1084227584,0,0,0]
Movement Command Sending!
5.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
Movement Command Sent Done!

Comment: However if I connect to drone & hit TakeOff button:
Drone State:CONNECTING
FlatTrimCommand [ID=FTRIM,param=] 
Taking off
6738 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG ardrone.ARDrone-State changed from CONNECTING to TAKING_OFF
6738 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender -Q[1]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208]
Flying Up!
TakeOffCommand [ID=REF, param=,290718208]
Movement Command Sending!
0.0
0.0
5.0
0.0
13062 [Thread-6] DEBUG ardrone.CommandSender-Q[2]Sending AT command TakeOffCommand [ID=REF,param=,290718208]
TakeOffCommand [ID=REF,param=,290718208]
Movement Command Sent Done!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you're using to move the drone.

Comment: Alright,Sir. I did edited my question with my java code to move the drone. Please kindly help to solve this problem. Thanks again. Very appreciated much.

Comment: Any idea on how to debug and make these codes working ? Help please ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a short sample program that I just tested on my drone.

Comment: Thanks John. I will give it a try and I will let you know how the drone works. Appreciated your effort.

Comment: @DennisQT I'm just curious whether you got this to work.